# whats is FieldType.nested in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I have below code that I am trying to understand.

```

```
class Member {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(optional = false,
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @MapsId
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private Reference reference;
}
```

```

Basically I started analyzing this class because we have n+1 issue with Member. It was originated from `@ManyToOne` relationship, so I added `@Batchsize` on top of `Member` and got my problem partially solved. Its partially solved because the other `@OneToOne` relationship is still triggering n queries. I thought of converting this relationship into `Lazy` and annotate with `BatchSize`, but I could not understand its impact considering above two annotations - `MapsId` and `@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)`

Can someone please help me understand these annotations and the possible impact if I make this relationship `Lazy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explaing all the three

**1. FetchType Lazy and Eager**

- If fetch type is Eager. When you call "Select * from Member" you will see another query being fired by hibernate "Select r from Reference where id = ?"
- If fetch type is Lazy 2nd query will not be fired until you do something like this

  ```
  Member m = getMember(id);

  m.getReference(); // Hibernate will fire another query.
  ```
- In most case I use LAZY

**2.  @Batchsize**

- In case of get call BatchSize behave like this
  eg:
- lets assume you have fetched 25 Member instances and each Member has ref to Reference. And Reference class in mapped with `lazy="true".`
- If you iterate through `mem.getReference()` Hibernate will, by default, execute 25 SELECT statements to retrieve the proxied reference.
- You can tune this behavior by specifying a batch-size in the mapping of Reference lets say to batchSize 10
- Hibernate will now execute only three queries: the pattern is `10, 10, 5.`

**3. FieldType.Nested**

- This data type should be used when you need to index arrays of objects and maintain the independence of each object.
- This means that the values for all of the objects will not be mixed together as you saw above.
- Internally, each object in the array is indexed as a separate hidden document.

  More Detail [here](https://codingexplained.com/coding/elasticsearch/field-data-types)

Comment: FieldType.Nested -> There is enough documentation available around NOSQL databases, and I have an impression that its something to do with nested objects. What I am not able to understand is, what its doing along with `@OneToOne` and `@MapId`, and what will be impact if I make this dependency Lazy load. Will it cause incomplete object fetch?